# Webdriver getText method with truncate using Java

Tags: java, selenium

Html Code

```
<table id="tblRenewalsFiled" class="StatusList" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: RenewalFilterModels">
   <tr>
    <td>
      <a id="aFilterMenu_NotAudited" class="aFilter" 
         data-bind="click: $parent.ShowFilter, attr:{'id':'aFilterMenu_' + StatusName}" href="#">
Not Audited
        <span class="count">13</span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

from the above, when I use the `getText`, method it will return "`Not Audited 13`"

```
String filterValue = driver.findElement(By.id("aFilterMenu_NotAudited").getText();
```

my expectation was only for `Not Audited`, provide an solution or suggestion to truncate the span class count i.e "13"

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.className("count")` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. So all I can to advice is to take cssSelector "a.aFilter, span", it will return an array of two elements `[ 'Not Audited 13', '13' ]`

   String[] value = driver.findElement(By.id("aFilterMenu_NotAudited").getText();

then you are truncating the second element from the end of the first one:

```
String myText = value[0].substring(0, value[0].length() - value[1].length());
```

Looks like a bit tricky.

2. Another way is using xpath:

`//a[@class='aFilter'][not(self::span)]/text()`